# 404 error in ubuntu, static/jquery.min.js/ HTTP 1,.1/ 404-

Tags: flask

I developed a chatbot with Python and flask, created an environment in ubuntu, and saved all the files in it.
after going to my website, I have to enter a question in the input bar and it has to give me a response.
Instead, it is displaying the below error in ubuntu when I enter a question and click on the send button.

"GET /static/jquery.min.js HTTP/1.1" 404 -

my website:
[website image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dIipT.jpg)

please help me with my error

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: tried this github repo https://github.com/tatiblockchain/python-deep-learning-chatbot/blob/main/python-deep-learning-chatbot/chatbot.py